# Inserting a block of JavaScript code into a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, templates, include, smarty

A friend of mine wanted me to gather some statistics for his website so I gave him the following code to insert in his page footers:

```
<div>
    <script>
       var wandTopSitesUserId;
       match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("WandTopWildlifeSites" + '=([^;]+)'));
       if (match)
          wandTopSitesUserId = match[1];
       else {
          wandTopSitesUserId = (+new Date * Math.random()).toString(36).slice(2, 12);
          document.cookie = 'WandTopWildlifeSites=' + wandTopSitesUserId + '; expires=Tue, 1 Jan 2030 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';
       }

       document.write('<div style="visibility: hidden;"><a href="http://www.www.fxxxxx.com/"><img src="http://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Log/LogVisit/?siteId=2&userId=' + wandTopSitesUserId + '&pageName=' + location.pathname + '" alt="WAND Top Wildlife Sites" /></a></div>');
    </script>
 </div>
```

What I didn't know is that he's using PHP and I know absolutely nothing about PHP. When he attempts to insert my code into his PHP script, he gets the following error:

```
string(125) "Smarty error: [in globalcontent:footer line 9]: [plugin] unknown tag - 'wandTopSitesUserId' (core.load_plugins.php, line 198)" string(137) "Smarty error: [in globalcontent:footer line 9]: syntax error: unrecognized tag 'wandTopSitesUserId' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 590)"
```

Not knowing anything about PHP, I have idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He uses the samrty template engine which requires you to escape javascript by encapsulating it within `{literal}...{/literal}`:

```
<div>
    {literal}
    <script>
       var wandTopSitesUserId;
       match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("WandTopWildlifeSites" + '=([^;]+)'));
       if (match)
          wandTopSitesUserId = match[1];
       else {
          wandTopSitesUserId = (+new Date * Math.random()).toString(36).slice(2, 12);
          document.cookie = 'WandTopWildlifeSites=' + wandTopSitesUserId + '; expires=Tue, 1 Jan 2030 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';
       }

       document.write('<div style="visibility: hidden;"><a href="http://www.www.fxxxxx.com/"><img src="http://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Log/LogVisit/?siteId=2&userId=' + wandTopSitesUserId + '&pageName=' + location.pathname + '" alt="WAND Top Wildlife Sites" /></a></div>');
    </script>
    {/literal}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just sent this to him and I should know soon if it works.

Comment: Send him this link for further documentation: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal.tpl